# Wordpress Genesis Theme Wrong MIME Type

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, mime-types

I built a childtheme based on the Wordpress Genesis Theme. I deployed it on my testing server and it worked. When I uploaded it to the client's site though, it breaks.

The problem is with loading the stylesheet from the childtheme. The error is:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://buyinginbergen.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/CustomBergenTheme/style.css/?ver=1.9.0".

Obviously the site is http://buyinginbergen.com/wordpress/. I haven't been able to figure out how to specify the file type, especially because I don't have FTP access so I had to build elsewhere before deploying.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similiar issue - the mime type of the css files the server sent back were wrong. We solved it by adding:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

to the .htaccess file in the wordpress root folder.